# How can I determine what flash player version a swf was published for?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a SWF of unknown origin, and I need to know which flash player version it was targeted at when it was published. How do I get this info?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The 4th byte in the SWF file carries the version number, for example 0A is for Flash Player 10.

EDIT: Because of the high interest this question got I've decided to give more feedback

The first 8 bytes of any SWF file are not compressed, the rest of the file could be compressed (or not) by zlib compression.

- 1st byte: 'F' (not compressed) OR 'C' (compressed).
- 2nd byte: 'W' always.
- 3rd byte: 'S' always.
- 4th byte: version number (09 means this file is targeted at Flash Player 9 and so on...)
- 5th to 8th: Length of entire file in bytes.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's flash player 10. How might I differentiate 10 and 10.1? http://www.johndierks.com/img/flashversionhexdump.png

Comment: The SWF file itself is not targeted into a specific minor version of Flash Player.

Comment: As I posted below, this tells you the version of the SWF specification that your file follows, but not the minimum Flash player version required.

Comment: @LordCover Hi, please tell me which version does this signify - 'FWSh  ˆ  Uð     (É @ 3Y   ' because I am not getting in this..

Comment: I think the file you're trying to experiment with got corrupted or has some sort of obfuscation, since normally the 4th byte is 09 or 0A or 0B (i.e. the version number).

Answer (score 13):

The Flex SDK contains a tool called swfdump that displays all of the metadata inside of a SWF file.  Here is the beginning of the output when I run "swfdump foo.swf":

```
<swf xmlns='http://macromedia/2003/swfx' version='9' framerate='24' size='10000x7500' compressed='true'>
```

Answer (score 12):

This adds on what brian sharon said.

Yes the 1-to-1 mapping of swf-version and Flash Player version is no longer there.

What the **4th byte depicts is the -swf-version, and what's good about this is that there is now a one to one relation with point releases**.

Look at these **references**:
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2011/08/16/versioning-in-flash-runtime-swf-version/
http://sleepydesign.blogspot.in/2012/04/flash-swf-version-meaning.html

From the second link:

```
Compiler Option     Flash Player Version
-swf-version=9      9
-swf-version=10     10, 10.1
-swf-version=11     10.2
-swf-version=12     10.3
-swf-version=13     11.0
-swf-version=14     11.1
-swf-version=15     11.2
-swf-version=16     11.3
```

I am using this information from flash game files to warn users that their flash player might be outdated on my flash games portal. And this works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Most - all? - of the answers so far are incorrect, which is unfortunate as I was hoping to find an answer to this question :).

Byte 4 of the SWF indicates what version of the SWF file format is used by the SWF. That is **not** the same as the target player version.

The minimum player version is set at compile time through the compiler option target-player, while the SWF file format version is set through the option swf-version.

The default values for these options can be found inside FLEX_SDK/frameworks/flex-config.xml. For the SDK version I'm using (4.5.1), the defaults are as follows:

```
    <!-- Specifies the minimum player version that will run the compiled SWF. -->
   <target-player>10.2.0</target-player>

    <!-- Specifies the version of the compiled SWF -->
    <swf-version>11</swf-version>
```

This means swfversion.com shows 11 for my SWF, even though I only require users to have 10.2. And according to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html, Flex 4.6 sets target-player to 11.1 and swf-version to 14. So I'm not clear how swfversion.com is at all useful.

Comment: Can you cross reference to a spec published by Adobe to support the claim that other answers are *wrong*?  My understanding was that the byte 4 thing still applied, but the translation wasn't one to one anymore between SWF version and Flash Player version now that there are minor releases.  It still stands, though, that you can't detect point release.

Comment: assuming that you are right, is there any way of finding out what flash player version a swf file is targeted at?

Comment: @MPD Brian is right, look at my answer for details, and here is the reference you wanted from Adobe - http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2011/08/16/versioning-in-flash-runtime-swf-version/

Comment: @AliVeli - yes there is a way and its even better now, you can know which point release its targeted for, look at my answer

Comment: I am completely assured of the fact that adobe flash sucks...getstacktrace doesnt work below 18 version and we are stuck without a stacktrace in the GUI..great

Answer (score 4):

You could use DoubleClick's Flash Validator tool:

https://flashval-temp.appspot.com/validator/

It will provide information such as SWF name, version, file size, dimensions, frames per second, compression, and total frames.

Answer (score 2):

Take a gander at the SWF spec from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf.html

Then do a hex dump or open the SWF in an editor that can display hex.  The SWF version is one of the first few bytes and is before the compressed data starts.  I want to say it is byte 4, but I don't totally recall.  The value is the version number.  IIRC, the point version is not encoded in the SWF.

GNU file may also tell you.  I may have edited my rules to do this, though.

Comment: Quick note about the point version thing.  Adobe has made some fairly significant changes to Flash Player mid-version (eg, H.264 support in 9.0.115).  When you add a SWF to a page you should really use swfobject and specify the point version to make sure the user has the proper player (and provide ExpressInstall if possible for them).  Determining the minimum point version from an unknown SWF takes some trial and error along with all of the archived Flash Players from adobe.com, as well as knowledge of what to look for.

Comment: Any tips on how this process goes? Just knowing the full version number is good enough for me right now, but I'd be interested to hear how this process works.

Comment: You need to check the release notes for the point versions, and look for the new features or things not working.  Then you guess if those features are being used.  Some are obvious (like H.264 support), others are more subtle.  You can also install the debug version of Flash Player which will let you see any exceptions.  You can often see a feature request in the call stack.

Comment: As I posted below, this tells you the version of the SWF specification that your file follows, but not the minimum Flash player version required.