# getting swf version info

Tags: apache-flex, flash

In FlashBuilder's compiler options (Properties->Flex Compiler), under "Adobe Flash Player options" there is an option for "Use a specific version", where you can tell it what Flash Player to link against:

[image]

How do I get this value at runtime?  Note that I am not talking about the Flash Player version, but the version that the swf was linked against.

Comment: That previous question Sean linked to was how to check outside of Flash. What I posted is used to check within Flash. So which applies to your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that exact target version.  You can get the SWF file version, but that is not the same.  When you edit the target version in that panel, Flex compiles against a different playerglobal.swc, but doesn't necessarily change the SWF file version.

Answer (score 2):

We were facing the same problem at my company, and we've found the following mappings:

```
 "SWF Version" | "Flash Player Version"
========================================
       9       |          9
      10       |      10.0, 10.1
      11       |         10.2
      12       |         10.3
      13       |         11.0
      14       |         11.1
      15       |         11.2
      16       |         11.3
      17       |         11.4
      18       |         11.5
      19       |         11.6
      20       |         11.7
      21       |         11.8
      22       |         11.9
      23       |         12.0
      24       |         13.0
      25       |         14.0
```

Sources:

- [blogs.adobe.com](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2011/08/16/versioning-in-flash-runtime-swf-version/)
- [sleepydesign.blogspot.com](http://sleepydesign.blogspot.com/2012/04/flash-swf-version-meaning.html)

Comment: This is also an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537076/chart-of-swf-versions-to-flash-versions

Comment: @paleozogt Thanks, I'll copy it to there.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not apply to your specific use case, you might need to explain what exactly you're doing. At any rate:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#swfVersion

Comment: So the "use a specific version" in Flash Builder actually maps to the swf version?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this with a project that you can modify or are you trying to find the version of a swf file after the build, if it's the former you can modify the index.template.html to include flash vars using the build variables as parameters then retrieve these at runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="absolute"
                creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Alert.show(Application.application.parameters.fpVersion);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

my index.template.html

```
<html lang="en">

<!-- 
Smart developers always View Source. 

This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
// -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<title>${title}</title>
<script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>

<!--  BEGIN Browser History required section -->
<script src="history/history.js" language="javascript"></script>
<!--  END Browser History required section -->

<style>
body { margin: 0px; overflow:hidden }
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
// Major version of Flash required
var requiredMajorVersion = ${version_major};
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredMinorVersion = ${version_minor};
// Minor version of Flash required
var requiredRevision = ${version_revision};
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body scroll="no">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)
var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

// Version check based upon the values defined in globals
var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
    // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
    var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
    var MMredirectURL = window.location;
    document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
    var MMdoctitle = document.title;

    AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+"&MMplayerType="+MMPlayerType+"&MMdoctitle="+MMdoctitle+"&fpVersion="+requiredMajorVersion+requiredMinorVersion+requiredRevision+"",
        "width", "${width}",
        "height", "${height}",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "${application}",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "${bgcolor}",
        "name", "${application}",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "${swf}",
            "width", "${width}",
            "height", "${height}",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "${application}",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "${bgcolor}",
            "name", "${application}",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "flashVars", "&fpVersion="+requiredMajorVersion+requiredMinorVersion+requiredRevision,
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
  } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
    + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
    + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
  }
// -->
</script>
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="${application}" width="${width}" height="${height}"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="${swf}.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="${bgcolor}"
                width="${width}" height="${height}" name="${application}" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is what you want to do you'll probably want to fill in the variables in the noscript block as well and add some delimiters for the version but I just wanted to see if this worked as I expected and if it's what you're going for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in December here: [How can I determine what flash player version a swf was published for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351370/how-can-i-determine-what-flash-player-version-a-swf-was-published-for)

Comment: That seems to be for reading a swf file.  I want the swf itself to print the version while its running.

Comment: Actually that answer might still be useful, although you'd be doing more work beyond what that answer says. Basically, you can have the code in the swf read in the binary data of the swf and check that. Modifying the binary while it's running would be crazy talk, but only reading it should be fine.

Comment: Oh that's a good point.  Way too complex for what I want, but it would work!