# Chart of SWF versions to Flash versions

Tags: flash

Is there a chart equating SWF versions to Flash versions? The beginnings of one is [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2011/08/16/versioning-in-flash-runtime-swf-version/), but it is incomplete. :(

Answer (score 57, accepted):

We were facing the same problem at my employer, and we've found the following mappings:

```
  SWF Version  |  Flash Player Version  |  AIR Version
---------------+------------------------+---------------
       44      |        N/A             |      33.1
       43      |        32              |      32
       42      |        31              |      31
       41      |        30              |      30
       40      |        29              |      29
       39      |        28              |      28
       38      |        27              |      27
       37      |        26              |      26
       36      |        25              |      25
       35      |        24              |      24
       34      |        23              |      23
       33      |        22              |      22
       32      |        21              |      21
       31      |        20              |      20
       30      |        19              |      19
       29      |        18              |      18
       28      |        17              |      17
       27      |        16              |      16
       26      |        15              |      15
       25      |        14              |      14
       24      |        13              |      13
       23      |        12              |      4
       22      |        11.9            |      3.9
       21      |        11.8            |      3.8
       20      |        11.7            |      3.7
       19      |        11.6            |      3.6
       18      |        11.5            |      3.5
       17      |        11.4            |      3.4
       16      |        11.3            |      3.3
       15      |        11.2            |      3.2
       14      |        11.1            |      3.1
       13      |        11.0            |      3
       12      |        10.3            |      2.7
       11      |        10.2            |      2.6
       10      |        10.0, 10.1      |      1.5, 2.0
        9      |        9.0.115.0       |      N/A
```

Source: [www.adobe.com](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/flashplayer-air-feature-list.html).

Comment: shamelessly copied from my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10895959/221213).

Comment: Can we get an update of those values? I see we're already at SWF version 31: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/flashplayer-air-feature-list.html

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your movie, Flash generates object tag and FSCommands automatically, if you choose Template: Flash with FSCommand in publish settings:

```
<object id="somePath\Untitled-1" align="middle" width="550"
height="400"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=11,0,0,0"
classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
```

where .../swflash.cab#version=PlayerVersion

**Or use latest player version, and all will be fine!**

Answer (score 0):

Adobe is keeping this list updated: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/flashplayer-air-feature-list.html