# myApp.swf is not start with adl.exe or flash player

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

I want to have stack trace from uncaught errors in production version in my AIR app (flex_sdk_4.6.0.23201B),

I catch errors. And show stack trace like this:

```
private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    if (event.error is Error)
    {
        var error:Error = event.error as Error;
        trace(error.getStackTrace());
    }
    else if (event.error is ErrorEvent)
    {
        var errorEvent:ErrorEvent = event.error as ErrorEvent;
        // do something with the error
    }
    else
    {
        // a non-Error, non-ErrorEvent type was thrown and uncaught
    }
}
```

There is the same situation:
http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/Workaround-to-solve-faulty-verbose-stacktraces-true-compiler-parameter-td7685.html

Author use  compiler options of project: -locale en_US -swf-version=23 -verbose-stacktraces=true

My project was on flex_sdk_4.5, there is default swf-version=11, but when set it 23, it compiling good and fault while I launch it:

> The application could not be installed because the installer file is damaged. Try obtaining a new installer file from the application author.

Is it some problem with source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADL error while loading initial content Adobe air](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428278/adl-error-while-loading-initial-content-adobe-air)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in xml descriptor, I had old namespace

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6">
```

I switched it to

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4">
```

Now my air can load swf-version=17

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428278/adl-error-while-loading-initial-content-adobe-air) I found the answer