# Can we use Flash Player 11 abilities through Flex SDK 4.5.1?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash, flash-player-11

As you know *BitmapData* has some limitation for image size and resolution in Flash Player 10 (maximum resolution is 8192) and for Flash Player version 11 and later, Adobe fixed this limitation and depends on OS we can have all type of huge resolutions in BitmapData.
But my problem is now I'm using Flex SDK 4.5.1 which base Flash Player is 10.2.159.1.

So is there any possibility to use this benefit of Flash Player 11 with my current Flex SDK with implementing a restriction based on Flash version with something like *Capabilities.version* or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have to :

- add the `-swf-version=XX` arguments to your compiler settings
- add the `-target-player=11.X` arguments to your compiler settings
- optionally, grap the corresponding `playerglobal.swc` and duplicate your FlexSDK, replacing the original SWC file (this is if you need to access new APIs)

Here is a [comprehensive tutorial](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1968) on how to this, and also a [very useful chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537076/chart-of-swf-versions-to-flash-versions) to know what SWF version to use.

> So is there any possibility to use this benefit of Flash Player 11
>   with my current Flex SDK with implementing a restriction based on
>   Flash version with something like Capabilities.version or not?

Generally, I don't think the approach of targeting a earlier version and check the actual one at runtime will work because the Player, even if it's version 11.0, will try to act just like the 10.2 if this the version your SWF was compiled for. See the very beginning of this [presentation](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2008-develop/flash-player-internals-by-jim-corbett-and-lee-thomason/) for more details. Use SWFObject to set the minimum player version for your application.

However, since your need is support for larger images, which is somehow transparent to programmers, I am not sure it is actually disabled for older SWFs. That should be tested.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply @Antonie,
But based on our project policies, I don't want add these changes to my compiler... I want to use something like this:

if(myInstance.hasOwnProperty("newMethodInFlashEleven")) myInstance[newMethodInFlashEleven]();

Is there any new method to check it based on that?!

Comment: What do you mean project policies? You mean that you must support older Flash Player versions?

Comment: Ah. My Bad, Had mistake in some parts... Tanx for reply :)