# Application (.exe) that can get the ActionScript version of a swf

Tags: flash, actionscript, exe

Are there any programs out there that can be used to detect the actionscript version of a swf file from within an application? I came across several questions similar to this, but none contained any information as to where to find a command line executable program that returns one line only which is the actionscript version. (one line is ideal, but not entirely necessary)

I know there are many online tools out there that can get the actionscript version manually, but I need to be able to do this on the fly without any internet connection.

Comment: Better ask this on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @sashoalm Oh, i didnt know that was a thing. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4351564/492336

Comment: @sashoalm Unfortunately, I need the ActionScript version, not the flash player version, and swfdump was actually the first place that I looked.

Comment: When you say actionscript version, am I correct that you mean AS2, AS3? If so, why not just look for a common function thats AS2/3 specific to determine the version.